# printf output not affected by global locale?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, internationalization, locale

I cannot get the `printf` functions in Visual-C++ (VS 2005) to output thousands separator in my integers.

Note: Comments indicate that this is `printf`'s normal behaviour. However, C++ iostream *does* insert the thousands separator into numbers (tested with `std::stringstream` and `imbue`) so is this purely a feature of iostreams and isn't present in the "C" formatting functions?

Here's the test code:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // -> User locale
    _locale_t loc = _create_locale(LC_ALL, ""); // -> user locale for *_l version

    struct lconv *pLocalSettings = localeconv();
    printf("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, NULL));
    printf("Thousands separator set to : {%s}\n", pLocalSettings->thousands_sep);
    printf("Grouping set to: {%o}\n", int(pLocalSettings->grouping[0]));

    int i = 1000000;
    __int64 i64 = i * 2;
    printf("32 Bit integer output: %d\n", i);
    printf("64 Bit integer output: %I64d\n", i64);
    _printf_l("32 Bit integer output: %d\n", /*locale=*/loc, i);
    _printf_l("64 Bit integer output: %I64d\n", /*locale=*/loc, i64);
    _free_locale(loc);
```

The output is:

```
Locale is: German_Austria.1252
Thousands separator set to : {.}
Grouping set to: {3}
32 Bit integer output: 1000000
64 Bit integer output: 2000000
32 Bit integer output: 1000000
64 Bit integer output: 2000000
```

Upon further checking, it would appear that it doesn't work like this. I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US"); // -> User locale

    struct lconv *pLocalSettings = localeconv();
    printf("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, NULL));
    printf("Thousands separator set to : {%s}\n", pLocalSettings->thousands_sep);
    printf("Grouping set to: {%o}\n", int(pLocalSettings->grouping[0]));

    int i = 1000000;
    long long  i64 = i * 2;
    printf("32 Bit integer output: %d\n", i);
    printf("64 Bit integer output: %I64d\n", i64);

    return 0;
}
```

on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php (Can't find no permalink there.)

And the output is:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo
Locale is: en_US
Thousands separator set to : {,}
Grouping set to: {3}
32 Bit integer output: 1000000
64 Bit integer output: 2000000
```

Comment: are you sure that printf should do somethig like this?

Comment: I've never known %d to include thousands separators in its output...

Comment: @JoeZ - then *what* does?

Comment: The custom function which you are about to write after receiving no satisfying answer to this question :)

Comment: It appears Boost might help you.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html

Comment: LC_NUMERIC: Determines the locale for numeric formatting. This environment variable affects the format of numbers written using the e, E, f, g, and G conversion characters.

Comment: this looks to be the answer. neither o nor d use locale conversion...

Comment: If you were using `gcc`, you could have used [`strfmon`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Numbers.html).

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/1fe00d3eb602a0754873b536dc92fb6226759ee4/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c#L2057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me share what I learned here:

- `C` locale *does* contain the information regarding the thousands separator, *but this information is [not used at all](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)* by the `printf*` family of functions (unless you count the [flag extension](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) `'`, which isn't present in MSVC anyways)
- `C++` locale contains the info as well, and iostreams *actually make use* of it when formatting numbers ([numpunct facet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct))
- Setting the global `C` locale with `setlocale`does *not* affect the global `C++` locale set by `std::locale::global()`
- The correct code to get my formatted numbers ended up being:

  ```
  static std::locale user_locale("");
  std::wstringstream buf; 
  buf.imbue(user_locale); 
  buf << some_integer;
  ```
- For certain use cases a performance speed-up can be obtained by [using the facet directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384848/performant-way-of-formatting-numbers-according-to-the-users-locale-with-iostrea).

Comment: It might be worth adding that `std::locale::global(user_locale);` will apply to all streams opened in the future - i.e. they will be automatically `imbue`-d with it. Note, however, that if you use it as the first line in `main`, one must remember that `cout` has already been opened and therefore one must explicitly imbue `cout`.

Answer (score 3):

I found [IBM printf](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/printf.htm) document, which says the locale affects `e`, `E`, `f`, `g`, and `G` conversion characters.

Neither `o` nor `d` use locale conversion...

Comment: It should be noted that the locale used by the floating-point conversions is *only* for the decimal separator. The thousands grouping separator is not used by the C-Standard `printf` at all. However, there exists an extension where the `'` character can be included in the flags to get grouping according to the current locale. (See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fprintf.html).)

Answer (score 1):

On pages 90-93 of his book "The Standard C Library", P.J. Plauger presents the code for a function called _Fmtval(), which formats a floating point value using information provided by localeconv(). The caller specifies whether the value should be formatted as international monetary, local monetary, integer or floating point with a specified number of fraction digits. Part of the code handles digit grouping and the insertion of separator characters. This could be used as a guide for writing your own function.

The article at the following link by the same author provides a similar discussion to the book, and presents an almost identical version of _Fmtval(). Unfortunately the code provided with the article seems to contain some OCR errors. If possible refer to the book.

Standard C: Formatting Monetary Values, P.J. Plauger

http://www.drdobbs.com/standard-c/184402377?pgno=4

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the OP is getting printf from C mixed up with BASH's printf (which does have some locale features) ??

(I'm on CrunchBang 11 "Waldorf", derived from Debian 7 "Wheezy")

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC not set

For example:

```
$ printf "%d\n" 12345678
12345678
$ printf "%'d\n" 12345678
12,345,678
```

[BASH printf command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)
(see Field and printing modifiers)

Comment: GNU(?) printf already linked to: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html - this is the docs for the C-library function. I guess the BASH one is just a 1:1 wrapper.