# Does printf() care about the locale?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

`wprintf()` takes a `wchar_t` string as argument and prints the string in the specified locale character encoding.

But I have noticed that when using `printf()` and passing it a UTF-8 string, the UTF-8 string will always be printed regardless of the specified locale character encoding (for example, if the UTF-8 string contains Arabic characters, and the locale is set to "C" (not "C.UTF-8"), then the Arabic characters will still be printed).

Am I correct that `printf()` doesn't care about the locale?

Comment: It does care about the locale for some things. However, programs start off running in the `"C"` locale unless you change it.

Comment: `LC_NUMERIC` affects the appearance of the radix ("decimal point") and digit grouping separators (if the non-C-standard `'` flag character is supported, which it is in Linux).

Comment: Also see [printf output not affected by global locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20352438/608639) on Stack Overflow. It was asked in the context of Windows, but I believe most of it is from the C and C++ standards, so it should apply equally to all runtimes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606668/which-components-use-the-locale-variables/50606965#50606965

Answer (score 3):

True `printf` doesn't care about locale for c-strings. If you pass it an UTF-8 string, it knows nothing about it, it just see a sequence of bytes (hopefully terminated by ascii NUL). Then, bytes are passed to the output as-is, and are interpreted by the terminal (or whatever is the output). If the terminal is able to interpret UTF-8 sequences it then does so (if not, it tries to interpret it the way it is configured, Latin-1 or alike) and if it is also able to print them correctly then it does so (sometimes it doesn't have the right font/glyph and prints unknown characters as ? or alike).

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider the following simple program, which uses `printf()` to print a wide string if run without command-line arguments, and `wprintf()` otherwise:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

const wchar_t hello1[] = L"تحية طيبة";
const wchar_t hello2[] = L"Tervehdys";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Current locale is not supported by the C library.\n");

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("printf 1: %ls\n", hello1);
        printf("printf 2: %ls\n", hello2);
    } else {
        wprintf(L"wprintf: %ls\n", hello1);
        wprintf(L"wprintf: %ls\n", hello2);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using the GNU C library and any UTF-8 locale:

```
$ ./example
printf 1: تحية طيبة
printf 2: Tervehdys

$ ./example wide
wprintf: تحية طيبة
wprintf: Tervehdys
```

i.e. both produce the exact same output. However, if we run the example in the C/POSIX locale (that only supports ASCII), we get

```
$ LANG=C LC_ALL=C ./example
printf 1: printf 2: Tervehdys
```

i.e., the first `printf()` stopped at the first non-ASCII character (and that's why the second `printf()` printed on the same line);

```
$ LANG=C LC_ALL=C ./example wide
wprintf: ???? ????
wprintf: Tervehdys
```

i.e. `wprintf()` replaces wide characters that cannot be represented in the charset used by the current locale with a `?`.

So, if we consider the GNU C library (which exhibits this behaviour), then we must say **yes, printf cares about the locale**, although it actually mostly cares about the character set used by the locale, and not the locale per se:

> `printf()` will stop when trying to print wide strings that cannot be represented by the current character set (as defined by the locale). 
> `wprintf()` will output question marks for those characters instead.

libc6-2.23-0ubuntu10 on x86-64 (amd64) does some replacements for multibyte characters in the printf format string, but multibyte characters in strings printed with `%s` are printed as-is.  Which means it is a bit complicated to say exactly what gets printed and when the `printf()` gives up on the first multibyte or wide character it cannot convert, or just prints as-is.

However, `wprintf()` is pretty rock solid. (It too may choke if you try to print narrow strings with multibyte characters not representable in the character set used by the current locale, but for wide string stuff, it seems to work very well.)

Do note that POSIX.1 C libraries also provide [`iconv_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv_open.3.html), [`iconv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html), and [`iconv_close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv_close.3.html) for converting strings, as well as [`mbstowcs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html) and [`wcstombs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcstombs.3.html) to convert between wide and narrow/multibyte strings. You can also use [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) to create a dynamically allocated narrow string out of narrow and/or wide character strings (`%s` and `%ls`, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the big virtues (perhaps the biggest virtue) of UTF-8: it's just a string of reasonably ordinary bytes.  ***If*** your code-editing environment knows how to let you type

```
printf("Cööl!\n");
```

and ***if*** your display environment (e.g. your terminal window) knows how to display it, you can just write that, and run it, and it works (as it sounds like you've discovered).

So you don't need special run-time support, you don't need special header files or libraries or anything, you don't need to write your code in some fancy new Unicodey way -- you can just keep on using ordinary C strings and `printf` and friends like you're used to, and it all just works.

Of course, those two ***if***'s can be big ones.  If you can't figure out how to (or your code editing environment won't let you) type the characters, or if your display environment doesn't display them, you may be stuck, or you may have to do some hard work after all.  (Display environments that don't properly display UTF-8 output from C programs are evidently quite common, based on the number of times the question gets asked here on SO.)

See also the "[UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)" manifesto.

(Now, with all of this said, this doesn't mean that `printf` doesn't care about locale settings at all.  There are aspects of the locale that `printf` may care about, and there may be character sets and encodings that `printf` might have to treat specially, in a locale-dependent way.  But since `printf` doesn't have to do anything special to make UTF-8 work right, that one aspect of the locale -- although it's a biggie -- doesn't end up affecting `printf` at all.)

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/1fe00d3eb602a0754873b536dc92fb6226759ee4/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c#L2057